# Modismos equivalentes de "Rise and shine!"

Tags: solicitud-de-modismo

I'll set the scene: preteen or teen-aged houseguest needs some friendly encouragement to get out of bed.

What are some pleasant idioms to use in this situation, equivalent to the English "Rise and shine!"?

Comment: Normally just a cheerful "buen dia" is the normal morning encouragement, or "buen dia, hora de levantarse" ... or hora de ir a la escuela ...

Answer (score 3):

There's always the good old

> Quinto levanta, tira de la manta...

which comes from a song for children

> Quinto levanta /
>
> tira de la manta;
>
> Quinto quinto,
>
> tira del colchón,
>
> que las doce son.

But this is not really a modism.

This will only address your question partially, but my friend's father, when she could not get out of bed because she had been partying last night until late (legal age to drink alcohol was 16 years old when this "story" takes place) would say:

> Noches alegres, mañanas tristes. Cabecita loca, ¿por qué no dormiste?

I also know of other parents using the *provervial* "levántate y anda" that was used with Lázaro in the Bible.

Comment: "Levántate y anda" sounds really good, nice and short and upbeat.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the proverb: "Al que madruga Dios lo ayuda". And, if the teenager complains because (s)he had a a long night, here we say: "Calavera no chilla" (meaning: If you had a good time last night, now you are not expected to grudge getting up.)

Comment: +1. Además, encuentro el "Calavera no chilla" realmente interesante. Hay una explicación breve y fácil sobre el origen? En España _un calavera_ viene a significar un hombre que sale con muchas mujeres (un playboy).

Comment: @Diego Aquí llamamos "calavera" al trasnochador, no necesariamente al "playboy". Aquí hay una buena definición del dicho: https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/calavera-no-chilla/